# Application Insights requires empty appsettings.json

Tags: azure-application-insights, .net-6.0, appsettings

I've made a new .NET 6 MVC application, installed 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore' and added `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` to Program.cs

Without an `appsettings.json` file no application insights information is logged, if I add an empty `appsettings.json` file logs do appear.

This seems an odd (undocumented?) requirement, is there something simple that I'm missing to avoid this?

We are handling config for app insights elsewhere and don't want to have to add an empty settings file just for this.

Comment: It may result from that ms recommend to set all the configurations of app insighsts in appsetting.json, so the source code may be set to going to read config file first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#configuration-recommendation-for-microsoftapplicationinsightsaspnetcore-sdk-2150-and-later

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @[Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15581227/tiny-wang) for your suggestion that helped lot.

The Application insights SDK for AspNetCore package **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore** Package required the appsettings.json file.

When you inject your application insights to your **ASP .NET core** application the **`service.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()`** requires the **appsettings.json** file. The Application starts when the configuration values can be read from **appsettings.json** file.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) for more information

Answer (score 0):

its better to add the "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING" key value pair in your Secrets.json instead of appsettings.json. secrets.json is local to your pc and will not be pushed to github or any scm.

[image]

The  `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` will look for the key `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` at runtime in your configurations

read more about Secrets.json at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows